# How to create login with user roles in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

There are two tables one is Login with Email id, username, password, name and where email id is primary key and the second table is Employee_role with id as primary key, emp_role, and emailid as foreign key of login email id.

here the condition is in emprole there is admin and whenver any user log in it first 
check if that emaild id is in employee_role if yes it would direct to "admin page" if otherwise it didnot find any emailid it will direct to "guest page"

Please i am fresher do help me...

Comment: Your question is hard to answer because you don't indicate what your code is capable of now. Do you need help with the control structure? Do you need help getting information out of the database?

Comment: Please check out the [ASP.net Website](http://www.asp.net), as they have a lot of examples and tutorials to get you started with the basics.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please i am fresher do help me...
```

We all started somewhere so no problem their. I know I see you got a number of downvotes. That is because you didnt really try much yourself or didnt share what you tried yet. Here is some general advice on your issues. You will need to look into them a little more, and get back with questions. I had to make a number of assumptions to get you started here.

```
There are two tables one is Login with Email id, username, password, name and where email id is primary key and the second table is Employee_role with id as primary key, emp_role, and emailid as foreign key of login email id.
```

I assume that you dont need specific assistance creating these tables. You obviously know about foreign-key and primary-key constraints.

```
here the condition is in emprole there is admin and whenver any user log in it first check if that emaild id is in employee_role if yes it would direct to "admin page" if otherwise it didnot find any emailid it will direct to "guest page"
```

Here is one way to acheive that in SQL:

```
SELECT l.email, l.userid, l.password, 
Case when r.emp_role is not null then 'admin.aspx' else 'guest.aspx' END as 
'TransferPage'
from dbo.Login l
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.employee_role r on l.emailid = r.emailid
WHERE email = @email  --Assumes you pass in parameter @email
```

Take the results of this query and compare the password of the returned query with the password of the entered text and if its valid then do a

```
response.redirect
```

to the page that the query returned.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank u for response . Can you little elaborate how to use the sql statement in the code that is in login.aspx